# For Loop within For Loop and If Statement

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML code (this is a snippet with what I am trying to work with).

```
 <products>
    <product>
        <productname>Name2</productname>   
        <productsize measurement="ml">250</productsize>
        <productsize measurement="ml">500</productsize>
        <productsize measurement="ml">750</productsize>
        <otherelements></otherelements>
        <price size="250" packsize="1">1.25</price>
        <price size="250" packsize="6">7.50</price>
        <price size="250" packsize="12">7.00</price>
        <price size="500" packsize="1">1.75</price>
        <price size="500" packsize="6">10.50</price>
        <price size="500" packsize="12">19.00</price>
        <price size="750" packsize="1">2.25</price>
        <price size="750" packsize="6">13.50</price>
        <price size="750" packsize="12">25.00</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <productname>Name1</productname>   
        <productsize measurement="ml">250</productsize>
        <productsize measurement="ml">750</productsize>
        <otherelements></otherelements>
        <price size="250" packsize="1">1.25</price>
        <price size="250" packsize="6">7.50</price>
        <price size="250" packsize="12">7.00</price>
        <price size="750" packsize="1">2.25</price>
        <price size="750" packsize="6">13.50</price>
        <price size="750" packsize="12">25.00</price>
    </product>
 </products>
```

What I am trying to do is display it like this

```
250ml 1=£1.25, 6=£7.50, 12=£7.00
500ml 1=£1.75, 6=£10.50, 12=£19.00 
750ml 1=£2.25, 6=£13.50, 12=£25.00
```

But it's no working and here is my XSL Code what and I doing wrong, I know it's got to do with the inner for loop.

```
<xsl:for-each select="x:productsize">
<p>
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   <xsl:value-of select="@measurement"/>
</p>

   <xsl:for-each select="x:price">
   <xsl:if test="productsize = '@size'">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>                                
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Do you have a declared namespace (if you do, please post the full source and xslt). In what context is your for-each? (please post the FULL xsl)

Comment: It seems like there will be more than one product in the source XML; if so, does each product have a unique identifier?

Comment: Yes there are namespaces all done, as **helderdarocha** has shown me. Apologies but a lot is missing and The page displays but I get no data. I know it's got to do with the nesting issue which **freefaller** has explained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your XML is invalid... you cannot have an element called `<other elements></other elements>`.  And your closing `<product>` should be `</product>`.  But I guess that is just written in there for the question.

The main issue is that `<price>` is not WITHIN `<productsize>`... therefore when you run `<xsl:for-each>` on the `productsize` you are searching for effectively `/productsize/price`

Try this instead...

```
<xsl:for-each select="product/productsize">
  <xsl:variable name="sizevar" select="."/>
  <p>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="@measurement"/> &#160;
    <xsl:for-each select="../price[@size=$sizevar]">
      <xsl:value-of select="@packsize"/> =
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>, &#160;
    </xsl:for-each>                                
  </p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This takes the value of the `size` attribute from the `<productsize>`, and uses it to find those `<price>` elements with the same `size` attribute

See this [XMLPlayground for a working demo](http://www.xmlplayground.com/K567KQ#sthash.Ocx20XGs.dpuf)

---

As per the OP's comments, the following line was matching all `<price>` elements in the entire document...

```
<xsl:for-each select="//price[@size=$sizevar]">
```

So I have changed it to the following, which will only find those elements in the parent (i.e. the `<productsize>` element the `<price>` elements are children of.)

```
<xsl:for-each select="../price[@size=$sizevar]">
```

Comment: Aha, thanks **freefaller** this worked, to all here yes I do have a namespace declared where I declare `xmlns:x="your-namespace" version=....`. My problem was the fact that I was searching in `/productsize/price` and `price` is not WITHIN `productsize`.

Comment: Hi freefaller, I seem to be having a problem with this code, if I have more than one product element it doesn't work [http://www.xmlplayground.com/Jl2XzC] I create a link here and you can see that is loads all the data from each product into the prices, I suspect it has something to do with the `//price[@size=$sizevar]` Don't know how to save that link :(

Comment: Change it from `//price` to `../price` which will only look for `price` elements in the parent.  `//price` will look for elements in the entire structure

Comment: I fixed it myself, well not really, thanks to **helderdarocha** i changed `//price[@size=$sizevar]` to `../x:price[@smoothiesize=$sizevar]` So I assume that if you use **//** instead of **..** it somehow goes back to root level? Which one is relative or absolute XPath?

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested my comment from 5 minutes ago.  Yes `//` will find the element anywhere in the entire document, but `../` will only look in the parent of the current element

Comment: Thanks, I should have refreshed the page instead of typing away. So I assume that `../` is the relative and `//` is absolute?

Comment: No problem  :-)  Almost, but not quite.  Yes `../` is relative, but `/` is absolute (it is the root of the document).  `//` is neither, as it will find the element anywhere in the document, irrespective of the current element you're dealing with

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your source has a namespace, it should have a `xmlns` declaration either in the `product` element or some ancestor. I will assume something like this:

```
<product xmlns="your-namespace"> 
    <productsize measurement="ml">250</productsize>
    <productsize measurement="ml">500</productsize>
    ...
</product>
```

In that case, you also have to declare that namespace in your XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:x="your-namespace" version="1.0"> ... </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, to obtain the result you want, you can use this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:x="your-namespace"  version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="x:product/x:productsize"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:productsize">
        <xsl:variable name="size" select="."></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@measurement"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../x:price[@size=$size]"/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:price">
        <xsl:value-of select="@packsize"/><xsl:text>=£</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for why your stylesheet didn't work, there are many possible reasons. If the namespaces are correctly declared, you are trying to read  `price` in the context of `productsize`, but they are not nested. You would have to access each price moving out of your context, either using a relative or absolute XPath expression. I used `../price` above, but it would also work with `//price`.

I am assuming that any other code you did not post and couldn't be assumed from your examples is not relevant. If you have other `product` elements or if `products` is not actually root, you will have to adapt the stylesheet.